# get EditText value from Fragment through onClick

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have created an acticity with multiple fragments. When inside a fragment a button (image) is clicked, the fragment is replaced with a new fragment. This works fine.
One of these images/buttons is the 'Add' button opening the addition page. In this fragment there are several EditTexts and a button 'Insert'.

When pressing the 'Insert'-button the Edittext values must be retrieved. This is where it goes wrong.

This is my code (I excluded what does not seem to be necessary):
MainActicity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
    EditText etDistancesInsertDays;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        etDistancesInsertDays = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etDistancesInsertDays);

        // On create display home page (HomeFragment)
        Fragment frRecords = new RecordsFragment();
        fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_container, frRecords);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();


    }


    public void openDistancesInsert(){
        fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new DistanceInsertFragment());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.frTitleDistanceInsert));
    }


    public void switchFragment(View view){
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnInsertDistance:

                // Trial 1
                EditText etText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etDistancesInsertDays);
                String strDays = etDistancesInsertDays.getText().toString();
                // Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Days: "+strDays, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                // Trial 2
                Fragment frInsert;
                frInsert = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frDistanceInsert);
                View frViewInsert;
                frViewInsert = frInsert.getView();
                // Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                EditText etText = (EditText)frViewInsert.findViewById(R.id.etDistancesInsertDays);
                String strDays = etDistancesInsertDays.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Days: "+strDays, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                break;
        }
    }

}
```

And my DistanceInsertFragment.java

```
public class DistanceInsertFragment extends Fragment {
    EditText etDistancesInsertDays, etDistancesInsertMonths, etDistancesInsertYears;

    public DistanceInsertFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View frViewInsert = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_distance_insert, container, false);


        // Set current dat in text field:
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        String strDayOfMonth = Integer.toString(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        String strMonthOfYear = Integer.toString(c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1);
        String strYear = Integer.toString(c.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        etDistancesInsertDays = (EditText)frViewInsert.findViewById(R.id.etDistancesInsertDays);
        etDistancesInsertMonths = (EditText)frViewInsert.findViewById(R.id.etDistancesInsertMonths);
        etDistancesInsertYears = (EditText)frViewInsert.findViewById(R.id.etDistancesInsertYears);
        etDistancesInsertDays.setText(strDayOfMonth);
        etDistancesInsertMonths.setText(strMonthOfYear);
        etDistancesInsertYears.setText(strYear);

        return frViewInsert;
    }
}
```

Both trial 1 and 2 gave the error "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException". Though I'm not sure wat is meant with it..

Comment: where is your button in activity_main layout or fragment_distance_insert layout? As i do not see any onclicklisterner defined.

Comment: i see you have a onClick method inside your Activity , does the button suppose to be inside one Fragment and the EditText inside another Fragment?

Comment: The onClick is indeed inside the Activity. The Button and EditText are inside the same Fragment. My mistake was already found by Aaron, I assigned the strDays wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should the code not be:

```
EditText etText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etDistancesInsertDays);
String strDays = etText.getText().toString();
```

Here you are getting text from the EditText, in your code you are trying to retrieve from the id etDistancesInsertDays

Comment: My god. I failed here big time. Thanks for spotting this! Should I delete this question, since it's just a reading error.

Comment: No problem happy coding :)